# Date Mon==Sun was unexpected at this time

Tags: time, batch-file

I am getting Mon==Sun was unexpected at this time. I have no idea what I did wrong. All my if statement look good, so if someone sees something please let me know.

```
set day7=%DATE:~0,3%
set month12=%DATE:~4,2% 
set day365=%DATE:~7,2%
set year1=%DATE:~10,4%

if /f %day7%==Sun set day7=Sunday
if /f %day7%==Mon set day7=Monday
if /f %day7%==Tue set day7=Tuesday
if /f %day7%==Wed set day7=Wednesday
if /f %day7%==Thu set day7=Thursday
if /f %day7%==Fri set day7=Friday
if /f %day7%==Sat set day7=Saturday

for /f "eol=; tokens=%month12% delims=," %%i in ("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December") do set month12=%%i 

echo Today is %day7% %month12% %day365% %year1%
GOTO redo
```

Comment: This doesn't look like modem AT-commands.

Comment: Its just part of a batch file I have for my command line class. I need to display the date using the for command.

Comment: I'll change the tags to your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The IF command does not have an `/f` option, hence your syntax error.

Remove the `/f` option and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I was probably meaning to use /i,  but taking out the switch makes it work.